# Reformat a bibliography output

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the `biblatex-bath` style which after some initial help amending, has been great. However, I now need to modify the formatted bibliographic output for works with a `translator` field. The `.bib` entry is:

```
@book{luther_collected_2018,
title = {The Collected Works of Martin Luther: Theological Writings, 
            Sermons \& Hymns: The Ninety-five Theses, The Bondage of the Will, 
            The Catechism},
url = {www.scribd.com},
publisher = {e-artnow},
author = {Luther, M.},
translator = {Jacobs, C.M. and Cole, H. and Bente, F. and Dau, W.H.T. 
          and Reu, J.M. and Buchheim, C.A. and Grignon, R.S. and Lenker, J.N. 
          and Hotten, John and Steinhaeuser, A T W and Gillett, E H 
          and Bell, Henry and Massie, Richard and Reynolds, William M 
          and Fox, William Johnson},
date = {2018} }
```

which produces an output of:

> Luther, M. (2018). The collected works of martin luther: theological writings, sermons & hymns: the ninety-five theses, the bondage of the will, the catechism (C. Jacobs, H. Cole, F. Bente, W. Dau, J. Reu, C. Buchheim, R. Grignon, J. Lenker, J. Hotten, A.T.W. Steinhaeuser, E.H. Gillett, H. Bell, R. Massie, W.M. Reynolds, and W.J. Fox, Trans.). e-artnow. [Online] Available at: www.scribd.com.

I however need the output to be:

> Luther, M. (2018). The collected works of martin luther: theological writings, sermons & hymns: the ninety-five theses, the bondage of the will, the catechism. Translated by C. Jacobs, H. Cole, F. Bente, W. Dau, J. Reu, C. Buchheim, R. Grignon, J. Lenker, J. Hotten, A.T.W. Steinhaeuser, E.H. Gillett, H. Bell, R. Massie, W.M. Reynolds, and W.J. Fox. e-artnow. [Online] Available at: www.scribd.com.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, british, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
urlfrom = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
\bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}%
\addspace
\bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}%
\addcolon\space
\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\bibliography{zotero.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{luther_collected_2018}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it really ok to render "Martin Luther" as "martin luther"? Please advise.

Comment: @mico It would be better if all capitalisation in the titles using `biblatex-bath` appeared in the bibliography for me personally, however it's an issue I have lived with. :-)

Comment: @JasonHigginson, just write words you need capitalized like `{M}artin {L}uther`, what is in braces is left alone. You'll also need e.g. `{\'a} {\"o}` for "á ö" (there are several other accents, BibTeX doesn't grok non-ASCII).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses around the translator is an explicit feature of `biblatex-bath`. The standard styles are much closer to the output you want in that regard.

We can change the two bibmacros `bytranslator` and `bytranslator+others` so that their definition from `bath.bbx` ([ll. 220-228](https://github.com/alex-ball/bathbib/blob/e2aad742e1d2a67bf201515b883287990161061d/biblatex/biblatex-bath.dtx#L2341-L2349) and [ll. 247-257](https://github.com/alex-ball/bathbib/blob/e2aad742e1d2a67bf201515b883287990161061d/biblatex/biblatex-bath.dtx#L2368-L2378)) is again closer to the definitions from `biblatex.def` ([ll. 2645-2650](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2645-L2650) and [ll. 2666-2674](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2666-L2674)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, british, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{datelabel}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \bibsentence\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}%
  \addspace
  \bibsentence\bibstring{urlfrom}%
  \addcolon\space
  \url{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}[1][bytranslator]{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[#1]{translator}%
     \clearname{translator}}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}[1][bytranslator]{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytranslator+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[#1]{translator}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{withothers}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{luther_collected_2018,
  author     = {Luther, M.},
  title      = {The Collected Works of {Martin Luther}: Theological Writings, 
                Sermons \& Hymns: The Ninety-five Theses, The Bondage of the Will, 
                The Catechism},
  translator = {Jacobs, C.M. and Cole, H. and Bente, F. and Dau, W.H.T. 
                and Reu, J.M. and Buchheim, C.A. and Grignon, R.S. and Lenker, J.N. 
                and Hotten, John and Steinhaeuser, A T W and Gillett, E H 
                and Bell, Henry and Massie, Richard and Reynolds, William M 
                and Fox, William Johnson},
  publisher  = {e-artnow},
  date       = {2018},
  url        = {http://example.com/~joerg/collected.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{luther_collected_2018,cicero,aristotle:physics}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Luther, M. (2018). The collected works of Martin Luther: theological writings, sermons & hymns: the ninety-five theses, the bondage of the will, the catechism. Trans. by C. Jacobs, H. Cole, F. Bente, W. Dau, J. Reu, C. Buchheim, R. Grignon, J. Lenker, J. Hotten, A.T.W. Steinhaeuser, E.H. Gillett, H. Bell, R. Massie, W.M. Reynolds and W.J. Fox. e-artnow. [Online] Available at: http://example.com/~joerg/collected.pdf.]

---

Note that you can protect certain bits of the title from the capitalisation change by wrapping it in curly braces. So you would write

```
title      = {The Collected Works of {Martin Luther}: Theological Writings, 
              Sermons \& Hymns: The Ninety-five Theses, The Bondage of the Will, 
              The Catechism},
```

to make sure that Martin Luther does not come out as "martin luther". I wasn't too sure about the capitalisation status of the other names in the title (The Ninety-five Theses, The Bondage of the Will, The Catechism), maybe they need protection as well.

If you want to completely turn off sentence casing, add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{midsentencecase}{#1}
```

to your document.

---

If you want to see

> Translated by

instead of the abbreviated

> Trans. by

you have two options.

1. Load `biblatex` with the option `abbreviate=false,`. That will result in bibstrings using the long form (such as "translated" instead of "trans."), but potentially affects much more in your bibliography than just this one phrase.
2. Redefine only the relevant bibstring(s)

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
     bytranslator = {translated \lbx@lfromlang\ by},
   }
   \makeatother
   ```

   `biblatex` has support for "combined roles" as well, so you may need to change those as well. See [`english.lbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx) for more strings and definitions. Note that the string definitions in `\DefineBibliographyStrings` can only have one form.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for your help again! Is it possible to change trans. by to Translated by if not I can certainly live with the modification you have kindly offered above.

Comment: @JasonHigginson See the edit at the end, please.

Comment: Thank you! I may get the hang of this one day.